# Forbid links to txternal images

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

is there a way to forbid external images in my forum? links to external images are somtimes broken, and not always legal.
Is it possible to make this via .htaccess?

Comment: The .htaccess controls the serving of files on your own Apache server. Depending on your forum software (e.g., phpbb), you should be able to block external image links through there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `< a href='' >` and `< img src='' >` ask the client to load the defined uri. There is no secure way to forbid this (javascript solutions can be disabled) as the uri is loaded by your browser and not by the server.

User generated tags in a forum can always be a security threat and should be filtered out. Depending on your code it may be possible for a hostile website to include code that reads client side session cookies with the rights of your respective page.

if you work with php you may want to use the `$str = strip_tags($str)` function. Note that nested tags may not be detected properly.

A security threat could also be based on `CDATA` or `html-comments`. If you work with highcommas or double quote in `< input >` tags it could be useful to also replace these by an empty string.

If you work with utf-8 you could do it that way:

```
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
$str = mb_eregi_replace( '\'' , '' , $str);
$str = mb_eregi_replace( '<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>' , '' , $str);
$str = mb_eregi_replace( '<\/([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>' , '' , $str);
$str = mb_eregi_replace( '<!--' , '' , $str);
$str = mb_eregi_replace( '-->' , '' , $str);
$str = mb_eregi_replace( '<!\[CDATA\[' , '' , $str);
$str = mb_eregi_replace( '\]\]>' , '' , $str);
```